# How to change the scope for search on Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, search

I want to search only for content in my site and to delete all office 365 Apps.
How can I manage the scope for search?

Comment: You mean from PowerShell, correct?

Comment: @MartinMuldoon No, I mean in the manage result sources, how can I get only the content added on the site and not the One Note, Teams, Yammer...

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I depict below, edit the web part for Search Results, and click Change Query.  Then in the panel that pops up, Click the Property Filter drop down.  Then select the Content Types you want included in your search result.  These must be separated by a space.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hello use **Search Content Query Web-Part** and as filter use `Path:https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/*`.

[MS Documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/building-search-queries-in-sharepoint)